# Downloading multiple images in Codeigniter using iframe

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe

I have a website in codeigniter and I need to give an option to user to download multiple images.
Below is simplified code. Now when I run this code it generates only the first iframe and downloads only first file. What correction is required, so that it downloads both images?

downloadimages.php contains following code:

```
    $addtest = base_url().'admin/test_multiple_downfile/img1.jpg';
    echo '<iframe src="'.$addtest.'">/iframe>';
    
    $addtester = base_url().'admin/test_multiple_downfile/img2.jpg';
    echo '<iframe src="'.$addtester.'">/iframe>';
```

admin.php  under controller folder contains following code:

```
    public function test_multiple_downfile()
    {
        $this->include_all_helpers_database_session();
        $id['id'] = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
        $this->load->view("multiple_downfile",$id);
    }
```

multiple_downfile.php contains following code:

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('download');
$file_data = file_get_contents(base_url()."attachments/ur136/".$id);
$file_name = $id;
force_download($file_name, $file_data);
?>
```

I am new to php and codeigniter, so I might be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Try to change your code to:  $id = $this->uri->segment('3');                                          
                                                                                                                                       
But the user must click on each iframe image. Otherwise I would ditch the iframes and just create checkbox array and user could select which ones they want and then your controller would just go thru a loop to force download the checked ones. Then the controller goes to the view to simply say: All done!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Ideally, I would also like to skip iframe but I am quite surprised to not be able to find any easy option to download multiple images in one go as I have seen some places that multiple files download at the same time. 
There are going to 7-10 files and I don't want customer needing to click each checkbox  but rather have option of "check all" so that it download all files one after another. Any way to do that with php and codeigniter?

Comment: you can set all the checkboxes to "checked" by default in html. then one download button. <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id123" value="123" checked> user clicks  submit button and your controller loops over the array of id's. otherwise maybe use a loop with a jquery script.

Comment: Thanks, will try and report here.